# Solving a tricky differential eqn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I solve this differential eqn

$$xdy - ydx = (x^2 + y^2)^{1/2} dx$$

I tried bringing the sq root term to the left and it looked like a trigonometric substitution might do the trick, but apparently no.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show any work that you have done?

Comment: I tried bringing the sq root term to the left and it looked like a trigonometric substitution might do the trick, but apparently no.

Comment: are you familiar with solving first order linear differential equations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = (x^2 + y^2)^{1/2} $$ is an ODE of the homogeneous kind. The usual method to solve it is to let $y(x)=x\:f(x)$

This leads to an ODE of the separable kind easy to solve.

The final result is $y=c\:x^2-\frac{1}{4\:c}$

Comment: Which equation did you solve ? Just by curiosity since you must have had a typo somewhere. Amitiés.

Comment: That is a solution for $c > 0$.  For $c < 0$ it uses the wrong square root.  It is a separable ODE, but not **linear**.

Comment: Hi ! The transformed ODE is : $x\frac{df}{dx}=\sqrt{1+f^2}$ it is separable , but not linear.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution $y = u x$ makes this into a separable differential equation.